# Request to Reopen someone's duplicate tagged question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-reopen

I found a question that is marked as duplicate, even though it seems to not be a duplicate and has a different intent. How can I get the question reopened? The question was posted by someone else (not me).

Comment: Post a comment stating why it is not a duplicate.  Anyone with close vote privileges (users with 3000+ reputation) can vote to reopen a question, if they agree that the question is in fact not a duplicate.

Comment: That question is not about reopening some other's closed question

Comment: Have you taken a look at the help centre yet?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions

Comment: give us the link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269856/how-to-split-comma-separated-string-using-javascript OP should need a solution that split and trim csv.(split with regex rather than just split with comma character).

Comment: @gnat, OP is other than me, so I can't do any rework on that question, other than suggest edit.

Comment: @NK if you see and can clearly write out the difference between the question, suggesting an edit to clarify this is the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can comment on the post itself or flag it for moderator attention (select `other (needs ♦ moderator attention)`). Explain why it should be re-opened, and a moderator will review it.

If you have 3,000 reputation (although it doesn't look like you do), you are able to cast a vote to re-open the question.